# Is $\Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$ cyclotomic?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, definition

[This overview of Galois Theory](http://nrich.maths.org/1422) claims that a field extension of $F$ is cyclotomic if it's obtained by adjoining an $n$th root of *any* element of $F$. Wikipedia claims you have to adjoin a root of *unity* (it also says you can only cyclotomically extend $\Bbb Q$, not an arbitrary field).

Which definition is correct? Are both in use? If Wiki's definition is right, what's the term for the one given in the other article?

Comment: For every $ N \in \mathbb Z$ there exists an integer $n$ such that $ \sqrt N \in \mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$. So, see both fields are same or not

Comment: to my knowledge, wiki is right. (btw $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})\subset\mathbb Q(\zeta)$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive 8-th root of 1, so in this sense it ic cyclotomic). Kummer extensions are (almost) what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the correct definition is, that for any field $K$, the extension $K(\zeta_n)$ is called a cyclotomic extension of $K$, for $\zeta_n$ being a root of unity of order $n$.
The word "cyclotomic" is used in this way for many other definitions, like the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial $x^n-1$, and so on.

On the other hand I have to admit, that the source you have given really says that
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. I think, this is not consistent with most of the other "cyclotomic" definitions.